# Unix Replace specific column with one value for another string

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I would like to change the fourth column of a file when I have the following description for it. I can not find how to solve it. When the string 1-8 appears I want to replace it with 01-08 but only in the 4 column separated by pipe.

```
SBMM01|CAM|22|01-08|NAP|VL|OPEN|1
CCSM01|CAM||1-8|NAP|CR|CLOSED|1
EZEM01|CAM|19|01-08|SPL|CC|OPEN|5
SPTD01|CAM|29|25-32|CDO|VG|OPEN|1
NRFL01|||1-8|NAP|CR|CLOSED|5
|||1-8|NAP|CR|CLOSED|5
```

by

```
SBMM01|CAM|22|01-08|NAP|VL|OPEN|1
CCSM01|CAM||01-08|NAP|CR|CLOSED|1
EZEM01|CAM|19|01-08|SPL|CC|OPEN|5
SPTD01|CAM|29|25-32|CDO|VG|OPEN|1
NRFL01|||01-08|NAP|CR|CLOSED|5
|||01-08|NAP|CR|CLOSED|5
```

How can change it with sed or awk in Unix?

Answer (score 1):

to change only the specified value

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $4=="1-8"{$4="01-08"}1' file
```

you can more generally format printing digits zero padding as well.

Comment: Can I do search by regular expressions in the column four by example?

Comment: Yes, or if you know the structure, split by hyphen and printf with required format.

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
sed -E 's/((.*|){3})(1-8)(.*)/\101-08\4/' infile
```

Comment: `s/^((.*|){3})(1-8)|/\101-08|/` might be better.